# PySys [0.9.2]. About running testcases when their ids are of the form 'token1<blank>token2<blank>...'

Tags: python, automated-tests

I've named a testcase as 'Delete Trades', so when I try to run it, from its parent directory, in any of the following ways:

```
pysys run Delete Trades
pysys run Delete\ Trades
pysys run "Delete Trades"
```

I always get the same outcome:

```
2016-06-19 14:18:41,405 INFO  Unable to locate requested testcase(s)
2016-06-19 14:18:41,430 CRIT
2016-06-19 14:18:41,430 CRIT  Test duration: 0.00 (secs)
2016-06-19 14:18:41,431 CRIT
2016-06-19 14:18:41,433 CRIT  Summary of non passes and tests requiring inspection:
2016-06-19 14:18:41,433 CRIT      THERE WERE NO NON PASSES
```

So, is there a way of invoking this testcase execution to work as expected?

Thanks, in advance, for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Is this on windows? A quick try (renaming the first example Fibonacci test) on linux shows that "pysys.py run Delete\ Trades" does work;

```
$ mv Fibonacci_test_001 "Delete Trades"
$ pysys.py run Delete\ Trades
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  ==============================================================
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Id   : Delete Trades
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Title: Python to calculate the fibonacci series - validate in
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO         memory
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  ==============================================================
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Calculating fibonacci series with ten entries
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Performing test validation
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Checking the tenth entry of the fibonacci series = 34
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Assertion on boolean expression equal to true ... passed
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Test duration: 0.00 secs
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  Test final outcome:  PASSED
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 INFO  
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 CRIT  
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 CRIT  Test duration: 0.00 (secs)
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 CRIT  
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 CRIT  Summary of non passes: 
    2016:06:19 13:31:42 CRIT    THERE WERE NO NON PASSES
```

Added - this is also working for me on windows (as below). Which version of python and pysys are you running?

```
C:\Users\moray\Development\pysys\trunk\pysys-examples\fibonacci\testcases>\Python27\python.exe \Python27\Scripts\pysys.py run "Del
ete Trades"
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  ==============================================================
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Id   : Delete Trades
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Title: Python to calculate the fibonacci series - validate in
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO         memory
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  ==============================================================
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Calculating fibonacci series with ten entries
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Performing test validation
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Checking the tenth entry of the fibonacci series = 34
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Assertion on boolean expression equal to true ... passed
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Test duration: 0.01 secs
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO  Test final outcome:  PASSED
2016:06:19 15:30:26 INFO
2016:06:19 15:30:26 CRIT
2016:06:19 15:30:26 CRIT  Test duration: 0.02 (secs)
2016:06:19 15:30:26 CRIT
2016:06:19 15:30:26 CRIT  Summary of non passes:
2016:06:19 15:30:26 CRIT        THERE WERE NO NON PASSES
```

Comment: Yes, Moray, this is currently happening on a windows system.